# why is android.os.Message not immutable

Tags: android, message, immutability

In android.os.Message, there are a lot of fields for another thread to identify what to do after receiving a message.

```
public int what;
public int arg1; 
public int arg2;
```

However, if we change the value in the fields after putting the message into the message queue, it'd affect the way the receiver thread handles the message.

**Why doesn't Android team make android.os.Message immutable?**
I think it'll prevent the Android developers to make mistakes.

**Isn't it a better design to make it immutable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no exact answer for first question (only android team has one). Looks like, it's related to some memory/performance considerations. Generally, creation of objects are quite expensive, so, Android [suggests](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) :

> the best way to get one of these is to call Message.obtain() or one of the Handler.obtainMessage() methods, which will pull them from a pool of recycled objects.

If You follow android reference and use Message.obtain(), you won't spent time and memory on creation new Message objects, but will re-use existing ones from the 'message query'. I believe Message was made mutable, because Android is for mobile systems with restricted resources (not sure if it's valid point today, but it was some years ago).

The same time immutable objects have many advantages. Check out Effective Java Item 15: Minimize mutability for more details. Main reasons for using immutable classes are:

- Immutable objects are simple;
- Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe; they require no synchronization;
- Immutable objects can be shared freely, even you can share their internals (whose are finals usually);
- It's easier to build other objects with immutable ones;

Effective Java mentions only single disadvantage of immutable classes: they require a separate object for each distinct value.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think you've got a great point! Since different message objects are mostly used to store different values, making message object immutable will require developers to create a new message object every time they need one, . Thanks a lot!